# PySpark: Using column name in UDF and doing concatenation of column names based on a logic

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe like this...

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| id2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| id3 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| id4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I would like to have a new dataframe which is based on this logic...

1. Accept any column which has positive values
2. Concatenate their names

**The result would then be like this..**.

| ID | NewColumn |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | A,D |
| id2 | B,D |
| id3 | A,B,C |
| id4 | A,D |

**My Effort:**

A) For the first step I thought I will convert the integers into the name of the columns...
So it will look like this...

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | A | 0 | 0 | D |
| id2 | 0 | B | 0 | D |
| id3 | A | B | C | 0 |
| id4 | A | 0 | 0 | D |

I was trying with a UDF but it did not work...

```
def CountSelect(colname, x):
  if x>0 :
    return colname
  else:
    return ""

countUDF = UserDefinedFunction(CountSelect, T.StringType())

cols = inoutDF.columns
cols.remove("ID")

intermediateDF = inputDF.select("ID", *(countDF(c, col(c)).alias(c) for c in cols))
```

BUT it is not working...

Can any of you help please?

B) Then I will use string concat function on all the columns

This part should be easier but still if you can combine both logic into a simpler working code, I would be really thankful to you.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it with UDF and let me post that here as well.

BTW: I modified a little bit and instead of making the final column as string with "," separated - I created a list and that serves my purpose better for the next steps in my project.

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, UserDefinedFunction, array
    import pyspark.sql.types as T

    def MakeOne(colname, x):
      return colname if x> 0 else None
    makeOneUDF = UserDefinedFunction(MakeOne, T.StringType())

    cols = inputDF.columns
    cols.remove("ID")

    def MakeList(arr):
      return [a for a in arr if a is not None]
    makeListUDF = UserDefinedFunction(MakeList, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

    outputDF = (inputDF.select("ID", *(makeOneUDF(lit(c), col(c)).alias(c) for c in cols)).withColumn("NewColumn", makeListUDF(array(*cols) )).select("ID", "NewColumn"))
```

Again, the NewColumn is of type Array Type or String Type and it stores the list of the columnnames.

```
| ID   | NewColumn|
|------|----------|
| id1  | [A,D]   |
| id2  | [B,D]   |
| id3  | [A,B,C] |
| id4  | [A,D]   |
```

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to mark rows across the columns which are `positive` and return the value of the respective column.

You can use [reduce](https://realpython.com/python-reduce-function/) to mark the columns and create a new `DataFrame` and Finally use [concat_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws.html) to form the required value

A more concise solution as provided by @anky

#### Concise Solution -

```
sparkDF.withColumn("GreaterThanZero",F.concat_ws(",",*[F.when(F.col(col)>0,col) for col in to_concat]))\
.select("id","GreaterThanZero").show()

+---+---------------+
| id|GreaterThanZero|
+---+---------------+
|id1|            A,D|
|id2|            B,D|
|id3|          A,B,C|
|id4|            A,D|
+---+---------------+
```

#### Data Preparation

```
input_str = """
id1 1   0   0   2
id2 0   3   0   1
id3 1   2   5   0
id4 4   0   0   1
""".split()

input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, input_str))

cols = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, "ID   A   B   C   D".split()))
            
n = len(input_values)
n_cols = 5

input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+n_cols]) for i in range(0,n,n_cols)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list, cols)

sparkDF.show()

+---+---+---+---+---+
| ID|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|id1|  1|  0|  0|  2|
|id2|  0|  3|  0|  1|
|id3|  1|  2|  5|  0|
|id4|  4|  0|  0|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

#### Reduce

```
to_check = ['id','A','B','C','D']

sparkDF_marked = reduce(lambda df
                , x: df.withColumn(x,F.when(F.col(x) > 0 ,x).otherwise(None))\
                        if x != 'id' else df.withColumn(x,F.col(x)) \
                ,to_check, sparkDF
            )
                      
sparkDF_marked.show()

+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|   A|   B|   C|   D|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|id1|   A|null|null|   D|
|id2|null|   B|null|   D|
|id3|   A|   B|   C|null|
|id4|   A|null|null|   D|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

#### Concat

```
to_concat = ['A','B','C','D']

sparkDF_marked.select(['id',F.concat_ws(',',*to_concat).alias('GreaterThanZero')]).show()

+---+---------------+
| id|GreaterThanZero|
+---+---------------+
|id1|            A,D|
|id2|            B,D|
|id3|          A,B,C|
|id4|            A,D|
+---+---------------+
```

The solution though works , but has some subtle nuances that you need to be careful off , especially the **reduce code snippet** and `to_check` and `to_concat`.

`to_check` can easily be replaced with - `sparkDF.columns` for the actual data , but do let me know the performance over the bigger dataset.

Comment: Yep , I figured that one out while creating this , I did not included that as I wanted to break the individual steps for better understanding. Added the concise solution as well , Thank you for the tip

Comment: This is great. In the meantime I have resolved it with UDF and let me post that as well. 

BTW: I modified a little bit and instead of making the string concat - I created a list and that serves my purpose better for the next steps. 

Thanks so much for the solution though.